# How to clean fields by ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, spring-restcontroller, objectmapper

I need to find the solution to remove items

```
@RestController
@PatchMapping
public User fieldUpdate(Long userId, String field) {
    User updatedUser = userServiceImplement.remove(Long userId, String field);
    return updatedUser;
}
```

Comment: Can anyone to advice?

Comment: `mapper.readForUpdating(user)` This here is wrong. ObjectMapper does not expose such a method. Please correct your posted code and also add your method `readForUpdating(user)` in order to be able to make sense

Comment: mapper.readForUpdating(user) is correct. it's Jackson

Comment: I still dont have the solution for clear fields, maybe need to change ObjectMapper settings..

Comment: can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you forget to call repository.save(User).

Comment: well noticed, but I just forgot this string here)

Comment: Is the 'updateUser' object really updated before being saved?

Comment: yes, it updates fine, but my goal is to clean.

Comment: Are you sure that the 'user' and 'updatedUser' have the same ID ?
Probably it performs insertion instead of updating

Comment: It seems curious. Can you send the SQL log?
You wrote that your updateUser has correct values from the JSON request after mapping by the ObjectMapper.
If the request consists of, for example, "name: null" then the UpdateUser has to have the 'name' field as null; Is it true for your case?